# Don't understand "Extra argument 'repeatedValue' in call"

Tags: ios, swift5, array-initialization

What could be wrong with:

```
let myArray = [UInt](count: 256, repeatedValue: 0)
```

that leads to the error `Extra argument 'repeatedValue' in call`?

I found this in existing code I'm adding to my Swift 5 app.

Comment: For future readers, see [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not Swift 5. The initializer name is [init(repeating:count:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/1641692-init) since Swift 3.